# Selecting an specific attribute from useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, react-hooks

With a React Class component i have the following state object as an example:

```
state = {
 typeEvent: [],
 reductionCoefficient: []
}
```

when i want to make a function that gets an specific attribute from the state i can simply use

```
getArray = (name) => {
 return this.state[name]
}
```

Is there something equivalent when i use Hooks? Because i would have to write this

```
const [typeEvent,setTypeEvent] = useState([])
const [reductionCoefficient,setCoefRed] = useState([])
const getArray = (name) => {
 if(name=='typeEvent'){
  return typeEvent
 }
 if(name=='reductionCoefficient'){
  return reductionCoefficient
 }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Variable" variables in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5187530/variable-variables-in-javascript)

Comment: using window doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply write your both arrays into one state:

```
const [state, setState] = useState({typeEvent:[], reductionCoefficient:[]});
```

Now just access them by their name:

```
state.typeEvent
```

or

```
state.reductionCoefficient
```